# Don't execute second command if first fails

Tags: linux, samba

I have to run two scripts, but 2nd script will only run if first script success.

`First script`

```
server_name=$1;
src_path=$2;
dst_path=$3;
dst_dir=$4;

cd $src_path;
smbclient //$server_name -A ~/\.smbclient -c "cd $dst_path;mkdir $dst_dir;cd $dst_dir;pwd; recurse; prompt; mput *; exit;";
```

Above script copy the contents from source path to a directory in remote server.

`second script`

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import sys
import os
import subprocess

project = sys.argv[1]
path = sys.argv[2]

print "\n inside second script"
fileName = "myfile.html"

file = open(fileName, "a")
if file:
    file.write('Release Locations:<br>\n' +
                 '<ul>\n' +
                 '<li><a href="file://' + path + '">file://' + path + '</a></li>\n' +
                 '<li><a href="smb://' + path + '">smb://' + path + '</a></li>\n' +
                 '</ul>')
else:
    exit(1)
```

`command(control don't go to 2nd script)`

```
./first_script.sh server_name/Shared /home/myname/work/target Software/target required_files && python second_script.py sony server_name/Shared/Software/target/required_files
```

`command(control don't go to 2nd script)`

```
./first_script.sh server_name/Shared /home/myname/work/target Software/target required_files || python second_script.py sony server_name/Shared/Software/target/required_files
```

`command(control go to 2nd script)`

```
./first_script.sh server_name/Shared /home/myname/work/target Software/target required_files;python second_script.py sony server_name/Shared/Software/target/required_files
```

On executing first script && or || with second script, control is not going into second script.

`status of first_script when run individually`: 0 (checked by running echo $?)

First script is successfully copying contents with some warnings.

If i run 2nd script individually it runs.

`warnings`

```
WARNING: The "idmap uid" option is deprecated
WARNING: The "idmap gid" option is deprecated
```

`Questions`

Because of this warnings 2nd script is not executing ?

How to make second script script execute ?

Comment: Please post your 2nd script. Please show how are you're calling them (e.g. exact command line).

Comment: Do you need the `exit` at the end of the command passed to smbclient?

Comment: @didierc yes, otherwise it will not exit from **smb:** terminal

Comment: @ElliottFrisch added 2nd script and command in post